# Canon LPB-6020 printer not working in LPR/LPD over ASUS RT-AC3200 router

Tags: macos, router, printing, network-printer, lpr

I just bought ASUS RT-AC3200 and I realized that it does not work with my Canon LPB-6020 printer over LPR/LPD protocol on Mac (Mac OS X El Capitan). I have installed it using this docs https://www.asus.com/us/support/faq/113661/ but it just not printing. 
On Windows PC (Windows 10) it also doesn't work over LPR/LDP protocol but **it works** using ASUS EZ printer sharing.

I can not find my LPR/LPD in http://gimp-print.sourceforge.net/p_Supported_Printers.php this list so I suppose that I can not use this.

Do you have any suggestions how to fix this problem if it is possible?

Comment: Also sometimes when I try to print it shows me this window: http://i.piccy.info/i9/bb4592ec2f6cc7899fb77038e9c4f708/1465638153/246102/1042582/Snymok_ekrana_2016_06_11_v_12_40_58.png  but cable is connected to printer and to USB router.

Comment: Btw. I am using latest Canon drivers to my canon lpb 6020 printer.

Comment: The 6020 looks like a GDI (host-based) printer, which are hard to network. If using a printserver (like your router) they require that the printserver specifically supports the printer. The only other way is to install it on a PC and share it. The Mac should then be able to use it. Most printservers manufacturers publish a printer support list but your router is not listed on http://event.asus.com/2009/networks/printersupport/